# JavaScript DOM changes in touchmove delayed until scroll ends on mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, classname, touchmove

In mobile safari, in the course of handling `touchmove` for an element, I change the `className` of that element. Unfortunately, the visual change does not occur while the user is scrolling, or until the very end of an inertial scroll.

What can I do to get the `className` to visually take immediately?

**More:** Apparently this isn't limited to className changes, but seemingly any change to the DOM, such as `innerHTML` and `style`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is by design unfortunately. iOS safari will queue up all DOM manipulation until the end of a scroll or gesture. Effectively the DOM is frozen during a scroll.

I thought I could find a reference to this on an apple developer page, but I can only find this link to jQueryMobile: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html.

> Note that iOS devices freeze DOM manipulation during scroll, queuing
>   them to apply when the scroll finishes. We're currently investigating
>   ways to allow DOM manipulations to apply before a scroll starts

Hope this helps!

Comment: Upon reflection, I guess it's so heavy DOM manipulation doesn't slow down the lovely inertia of the scroll.

Comment: Sadness. The more I tried, the more clear it became that this is the case.

Comment: Somehow, this site overcomes that limitation. Anyone understand what they did? https://victoriabeckham.landrover.com/INT

Comment: Very nice effect! I might be wrong, but it looks like they are overriding the scroll (in their touchMoveHandler method in ScrollAnimator.js they are using event.preventDefault) and just animating the visible area to look like a scroll is occurring. May be wrong, only look at it for a few mins, but it looks like thats the case! :)

Comment: A bit after the fact but [facebook home](http://facebook.com/home) does this fine on mobile (ipad)

Comment: Facebook Home is an app, not a webapp and so isn't restricted by iOS Safari issues

Comment: This is fixed in iOS8. Setting only a translateY on iOS7 works, albeit a bit choppy.

Comment: @PaulHachmang its definately not fixed yet on iOS safari. I am using iOS9, still same issue

Answer (score 15):

I actually built that site, and yes the way to get around this limitation is to not scroll the site using the built in browser functionality but fake it.  The JS listens to scroll wheel and keyboard events and tweens the css top property of the main container to its own 'scrollTop'.  The scrollbar on the right is of course a custom JS one.  In this case its synced to the same internal 'scrollTop' value.

The whole site is just one big tween really, with the main timeline being its scrollTop position, and all the sub animations being triggered at certain times.  The JS isn't minified so take a look in the ScrollAnimator.js file, its all there.

Comment: can someone provide a link? where is that site

Comment: Link is in the comments above https://victoriabeckham.landrover.com/INT The page doesn't scroll for me with two finger trackpad scrolling on a Mac / Firefox.

Comment: Link above seems to be broken. Can anyone post the example code?

Comment: It would have been nice to include the code of ScrollAnimator.js before the link went away :/

Comment: Well... is this the one you guys looking for? https://gist.github.com/domingl/6005178

Answer (score 4):

Simply change position to `-webkit-sticky`. Do not set top so it will look just like a normal element, but performs like a fixed element. And you can update its style except position immediately.

Comment: this works beautifully in iOS and newer versions of desktop safari.  What I did for the header was specifically for iOS I use this property, everything else uses the fixed, this is because of compatibility.  More about this property here: http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/08/Stick-your-landings-position-sticky-lands-in-WebKit

Comment: This! Incredible! I've been pulling my hair out for days trying to find solutions to animate something during touchmove and position: sticky; is exactly what I needed. I would have never come up with this on my own. Thank you so much!