# Parallax / Scroll effect using Edge?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flash, adobe-edge

Hi I need to basically re-create this for a client (https://victoriabeckham.landrover.com/INT) and I am struggling to think of a solution to give a timeframe for the work (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12461710/jquery-parallax-scrolling-effect-multi-directional)

Had the idea that I could build the animation using either Flash or Edge and trigger the play-back on horizontal scroll, though I'm not sure how to (or whether its possible to) reverse the  playback when scrolling is reversed?

Does anybody have any thoughts/Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Check out steller.js for a nice plugin that does must of what you need:

http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/demos/