# How to make scrolling parallax with one movement with scroll mouse

Tags: jquery, scroll, mouse, parallax

i have a problem. I need make a parallax like this http://community.saucony.com/kinvara3/. I know how to make the parallax but not with only one movement of the scroll from mouse.

One movement from scroll and the scroll runs straight.

Comment: dupicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12461710/jquery-parallax-scrolling-effect-multi-directional

Answer (score 0):

You should disable scrol temporary when scroll is triggered.

```
function disable_scroll() {
  if (window.addEventListener) {
      window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', wheel, false);
  }
  window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = wheel;
  document.onkeydown = keydown;
}

function enable_scroll() {
    if (window.removeEventListener) {
        window.removeEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', wheel, false);
    }
    window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = document.onkeydown = null;  
}
```

Comment: Mmmm ok, but what I do next? I'm trying with MouseWheel (jQuery) but unsuccessfully :(