# HTML 5 Layout design

Tags: html

Does anyone know the name for this type of layout design, or any sources on how to re-create?

http://kitkat.com/

http://www.theverge.com/2013/8/22/4645454/back-to-school-2013-the-verge-guide

Thanks Gary

Comment: The first one is something like an endless page with parallax scrolling. This technique became very popular last year by sites from Nike, The new Beetle (both offline by now) or [Super Mario Kart](http://www.nintendo.com.au/gamesites/mariokartwii/#home). Here's an example you to accomplish those effects: [Jquery Parallax Scrolling effect - Multi directional](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12461710/1456376)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are usually called : Full Screen Websites / Infinite Scroll Websites

Take a look at this :

http://www.awwwards.com/websites/fullscreen/

http://www.cssauthor.com/beautiful-fullscreen-websites-for-your-inspiration/

http://www.awwwards.com/websites/infinite-scroll/