# How to delete top divs without causing bottom divs to jump up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a situation where I need to delete the top-most divs in a document without causing any changes from the user's perspective. Basically, I need to go from:

---------top of document
div1
div2
div3
---------top of window
div4
div5
---------bottom of window
div6
div7
---------bottom of document

to:

---------top of document
div3
---------top of window
div4
div5
---------bottom of window
div6
div7
---------bottom of document

What would be the best way to accomplish this transition in a manner that doesn't cause the user to see div4 and div5 make any movement?

Comment: remove those div during loading the page, before it even renders or something? or when the page loaded? or when the user scroll down? an event triggered by user?

Comment: Remove when the user scrolls down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Heavily edited!**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var heightof = $('#one').height() + $('#two').height();
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var y = $(this).scrollTop();

        if(y >= heightof)
        {
            $('#one, #two').remove();
            $(this).scrollTop('0px');
        }
    });  
});
```

Here, this should work!

This code is basically checking for scroll event, and when it reaches past the first two divs (so we add their heights), we remove them. I didn't even noticed anything changes when I tested them.

check it out live on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e6p9b/)

Comment: But in this case, wouldn't the user still see a blank space if he or she scrolled up? That's why I want the top of the document to be the top of div3.

Comment: not unless you resize div 3 or do some manipulation to it. that's why a parent div can help you a lot in doing so. and there's many way to do it, but i don't know what else you need... talking about the looks, contents, or whatever related that might affect the presentation

Comment: @user1481479 here you go.

Comment: Works! Thank you. Only problem is that there is a lag on iOS. But that appears to be because of this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10482227/javascript-dom-changes-in-touchmove-delayed-until-scroll-ends-on-mobile-safari

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to set the document's `scrollTop` to the current one minus the height of the `div`s you are removing. Something like:

```
var height = $('#div-1').height() + $('#div-2').height();
$(document).scrollTop($(document).scrollTop() - height);
$('#div-1, #div-2').remove();
```

The change in scroll position should be fast enough that the user won't notice it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to actually remove the element from the DOM, you can set its `style.visibility` property to "hidden". It will disappear from the page, but there will still be an empty space where it used to be.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do need to actually remove it from the DOM, and I can't have an empty space in place of divs 1 and 2. The top of document should end up as the top of div3.