# Navbar show only when scrolling up in iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, touch, mobile-safari

I'm using the [Marius Craciunoiu technique](https://medium.com/p/67bbaae9a78c) to show my entire navbar when the user scrolling up.

So, this is my **JavaScript** (using jQuery) code:

```js
var delta, didScroll, lastScrollTop, navbarHeight;

delta = 5;
lastScrollTop = 0;
navbarHeight = $('.navbar').outerHeight();

$(window).on('scroll touchmove', function() {
  didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
  if (didScroll) {
    hasScrolled();
    didScroll = false;
  }
}, 250);

function hasScrolled() {
  var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();

  if (Math.abs(lastScrollTop - scrollTop) <= delta) { return; }

  if (scrollTop > lastScrollTop && scrollTop > navbarHeight) {
    $('.navbar').addClass('scrolling');
  } else {
    if (scrollTop + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
      $('.navbar').removeClass('scrolling');
    }
  }

  lastScrollTop = scrollTop;
}
```

To take it more easy, I post my code on http://jsfiddle.net/caio/7HrK7/. If you want to test in iOS, use http://fiddle.jshell.net/caio/7HrK7/show/light/ url.

**VIDEO:** http://hiperload.com/s/ua5k53n0x/d.mp4?inline

How as you can see, my code works on desktop and Android phones. But on iOS it need a touch event to respond while the scroll event still happens, otherwise it will only be executed at the end. I've tried to add `touchmove` event, but without success. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like iOS pauses all timers while scrolling. Perhaps you'll have some luck trying the technique here:

[iOS 6 js events function not called if has setTimeout in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12855123/ios-6-js-events-function-not-called-if-has-settimeout-in-it)

Alternatively, you can run `hasScrolled()` directly on `touchmove`. This seems to cause some flickering (at least on my iPad) so you might have to figure out a different way to animate the scrollbar:

```
$(window).on('touchmove', function() {
  hasScrolled();
});
```

See a fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/mariusc23/7HrK7/13/

Let me know if you find a solution so I can update the post. I'll spend some time on it as well. Thanks for reading. :)